# How can I identify Windows PnP events with Perl's POE?

Tags: windows, perl, poe

Is there a POE module that identifies PnP events in Windows? If yes, could someone provide idea code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can always write your own. [POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POE) is designed to be easily extendable.

The main module on CPAN for working with UPnP events is [Net::UPnP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::UPnP).

Comment: Plug&Play is something different from the collection of crap network protocols that is UPnP.

Comment: Damn Microsoft and their similarly-named protocols! *shakes fist*